# what is optimized for a faster database query, using JOINS or a seperate table with all relevant data

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to make my `vCard` and it pretty much has redundant information. Like my name, number, website, company name, my title (or in my case my group name title)

These values exists in a few tables

```
user_meta
company
groups
```

I could easily just make a vCard table and house all that information in there, but is that a good way to go? Or should I just `JOIN` to get the information from all 3 tables to populate my vCard.

Comment: maybe you can have a view that gets the info from all the other tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question is what you do. Manage VCards - then go with the vcard oriented model. Manage information where vcard is the output, then maybe get a copy of the Data Model Ressource Book and look how to design a good address and contact maangement system (hint: it is a LITTLE more complicated).

In general, both approaches have merit. The problem with copying data  are updates. It is often done when no / rare updaets happen, such as data warehouses. Joins keep the data size small, which makes processing easier, but require more processing power.

For a vcard management system I doubt it makes a difference. How many hundred thousand people you plan to enter?

Comment: well my thought was have something like www.foo.bar/someuser/vcard and have that point to vcard.php that does a query to pull the data that goes into the vcard. and that information is the same information fouund under www.foo.bar/user/someuser which points to profile.php. I mean its all the same thing, so I was wondering what would be less of a strain